# Download files from links in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to download files from links in an array with a length of several thousand positions. The problem is that when I iterate over the array I hit a wall when trying to synchronize the file fetch and write ( Maximum call stack size exceeded). I've tried to make a recursive function and played with promises but I still haven't managed to find a solution. 
Help please!

My code so far:

```js
function download(url, dest, cb) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let request = https.get(url, function (response) {
            let file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
            response.pipe(file);
            file.on('finish', function () {
                console.log('File downloaded')
                resolve(file.close(cb));  
            });
        }).on('error', function (err) { 
            reject(err)
        });
    })

};


function recursiveDownload(links, i) {
    if (i < links.length) {
      download(links[i], './data/' + i + '.csv')
            .then(recursiveDownload(links, ++i))
    } else {
        console.log('ended recursion')
    }
}

recursiveDownload(links, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop to serialize all your promises and synchronize them. Try the following:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve();
for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
  promise = promise.then(()=> download(links[i], './data/' + i + '.csv'));
}
```

Or you can even chain your promises using `Array.reduce()` :

```
var promise = links.reduce((p, link, index) => p.then(()=>download(link, './data/' + index + '.csv')),Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: you were so fast that I wasn't allowed to do it. Now it's done, Have a nice day :)

Comment: @alvcarmona Happy to help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because you call `recursiveDownload` immeadiately withou waiting for the download to succeed. You actually want to call it when `.then` calls back:

```
 download(links[i], './data/' + i + '.csv')
        .then(() => recursiveDownload(links, ++i))
```